# This regex_match function is not working correctly error code 7

Tags: regex, c++11

This is the code i am using

```
string exptype(string s)
{
string type = "";
try
{
    if (regex_match(s.c_str(), regex("101(0|1)*111")))
        type = "a valid binary";
    else if (regex_match(s.c_str(), regex("[a-zA-Z]")))
        type = "a valid combination of alphanum letters";
    else if (regex_match(s.c_str(), regex("\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-{0-9}{4}")))
        type = "a valid phone number";
    else if (regex_match(s.c_str(), regex("(19|20)[0-9][0-9]-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-   ((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))")))
        type = "a valid date";
    else
        type = "an invalid string";
}
catch (std::regex_error& e) 
{
    cout << e.code() << endl;
}


    return type;
}
```

Then my main is  the following:

```
int main()
{
string input;
do 
{
    cout << "Enter the string that will be validated.." << endl;
    getline(cin, input);
    if (input != "q")
    {
        cout << "This is " << exptype(input) << endl;
    }
    else
        break;

} while (true);

return 0;
}
```

The mentioned code will sometimes work and sometimes it will throw an exception with the error code: 7
I have googled it and found that the error is error_brace: The expression contained mismatched braces ({ and }).
I dont see what is wrong here, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The error occurs for all the patterns

Comment: `{0-9}` should be `[0-9]` in phone numbers

Comment: I tried that and i got error code 10

Comment: That's like moving 3 error codes forward. Way to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mariano pointed out, you should replace `{0-9}` with `[0-9]`. You also better use raw string litterals when dealing with regular expressions or other string with escaping `\`. For example:

```
regex_match(s.c_str(), regex(R"reg(\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})reg"))
```

Comment: I thought [0-9] meant range and {9} would mean repetitions didn't know it could be used for range too

Comment: I don't know what patterns you expect to catch with for example the snippet I used in my answer, but [0-9]{4} would be four digits.